# Mixed model ANCOVA when variables are not of the same length

Tags: r, mixed-models

I want to run a mixed ANCOVA with the Block as a within-subject factor and Condition as a between-subject factor. My DV is ResponseBias and my covariates are Age and mA. Here is an example of what my dataframe looks like:

```
Subject Condition   Block   Age  mA   ResponseBias
705        c          1     22   2.1  0.133297538
705                   2               0.109737012
705                   3              -0.064639146
706        u          1     21  0.9  -0.012777052
706                   2              -0.118587142
706                   3              -0.423479985
```

My question is, how do I deal with the fact that some variables are not the same length? Surely duplicating the Condition, Age and mA columns per subject ID to make them the same length would influence the ANCOVA?

I hope this makes sense, any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: replicate the repeated variables (e.g. using `zoo::na.locf` or `tidyr::fill`). The repeated variables are not a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. So the ANCOVA computation won't be influenced by the fact age, for example, is duplicated for each participants? it will somehow know this is the case or do I need to add another argument to my code to account for it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any such thing as a blank entry in an R data frame; it might be `NA` (the most likely possibility) or an empty string `""` in a character/factor column (but it *should* be an `NA`, unless you want "blank" to be an additional category). By default, R will *discard* rows of a data frame with `NA` values, if the `NA`-valued columns are included in a model ("complete case analysis").

So, you should almost certainly use a tool like `zoo::na.locf()` (locf = "last observation carried forward") or `tidyr::fill()` to replace those blanks with the appropriate values.

At which level the values of a predictor variable vary matters only at two steps of the analysis.

- *deciding how to structure the model*: in general, you should include random effects for all predictors that vary *within* groups, i.e. if `x` varies within group `g` then your model should allow for the possibility that the effects of `x` (i.e. slopes of `y` with respect to `x`) vary across groups, see e.g. Schielzeth and Forstmeier 2009.
- *inference after fitting the model*: if you are using a framework that allows you to use finite-size corrections (typically by using an F-test), then the *denominator degrees of freedom* should be adjusted based on the levels of variation.

### simulate some data

For illustration, I'm going to make up an example with a continuous and a categorical predictor that vary across groups (`age` and `ttt`), *and* a continuous and a categorical predictor (`x` and `t2`) that vary *within* groups.

```r
library(nlme)
library(lmerTest)

set.seed(101)
ss <- data.frame(id = factor(1:20),
                 age = seq(10, 20, length.out = 20),
                 ttt = rep(c("c", "t"), 10))
                 
dd <- data.frame(id = rep(factor(1:20), each = 10),
                 x = rnorm(200),
                 t2 = factor(sample(c("a", "b"), size = 200,
                                    replace = TRUE))
                 )
dd <- merge(dd, ss, by = "id")
dd$y <- simulate(~ x + age + ttt + t2 + (x + t2 |id),
                 family = gaussian,
                 newdata = dd,
                 newparams = list(beta = c(0, 4, 1, 2, 3),
                                  ## 3 x 3 cov matrix, need 6 params
                                  theta = rep(1, 6),
                                  sigma = 1))[[1]]
```

### fit models

Allowing the effects of `x` and `t2` to vary across levels of `id`:

```r
m_lme <- lme(y ~ x + age + ttt + t2, random = ~ x + t2 | id,
             data = dd)
m_lmer <- lmer(y ~ x + age + ttt + t2 + (x + t2 | id),
             data = dd)
```

### inference

```r
anova(m_lme)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1   178 11848.141  <.0001
x               1   178    25.549  <.0001
age             1    17   488.387  <.0001
ttt             1    17    54.349  <.0001
t2              1   178    78.693  <.0001
```

The `denDF` column shows what `lme` "thinks" is the level of replication for each predictor. The algorithm that `lme` uses (which involves counting number of parameters and number of observations at each level)  gets the right answer for `age` and `ttt`, but it gets the *wrong answer* for `x` and `t2` (since these are allowed to vary across groups, the correct inference should be based on the number of groups, not the number of observations ... This problem is [noted in the GLMM FAQ]([GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have)), and I link to some code that does a slightly better job.)

In contrast, the `lmerTest` package uses more sophisticated approximation algorithms (`lme4` doesn't give p-values at all), which give *approximately* correct answers. (In this case we know the correct denominator df for all four predictors is 17; the range from 16-20 should make little difference in practice ...)

```r
anova(m_lmer)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
    Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
x    99.12   99.12     1 18.939 110.983 2.338e-09 ***
age 411.70  411.70     1 19.803 460.956 3.475e-15 ***
ttt  44.57   44.57     1 16.846  49.898 2.003e-06 ***
t2   70.29   70.29     1 18.846  78.697 3.736e-08 ***
```

The Kenward-Roger method is more computationally demanding but usually more accurate (in this case it gives similar answers):

```r
anova(m_lmer, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
    Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
x    98.80   98.80     1 18.958 110.621 2.375e-09 ***
age 327.72  327.72     1 19.252 366.937 5.345e-14 ***
ttt  35.21   35.21     1 16.376  39.425 9.879e-06 ***
t2   69.71   69.71     1 18.908  78.047 3.876e-08 ***
```

Schielzeth, Holger, and Wolfgang Forstmeier. “Conclusions beyond Support: Overconfident Estimates in Mixed Models.” Behavioral Ecology 20, no. 2 (March 1, 2009): 416–20. https://doi.org/10.1093/beheco/arn145.